# getting json object and then assign to uitable view

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, uitableview

Well in my app I have a tableview. What i want to do is this:
fetch data over the web, store them in an array and then depending of the value of each index the corresponding row to get a background.

What I mean is this:
if data[0]=red---> image of row 0 will be red, else green.

I have managed to download the data, but problem is that images are first assigned and then happens the http request.

For example:
This is my code for getting data and storing them to array:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);

    // convert to JSON
    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    colours== [NSMutableArray array];


    NSString *parsed_data=[res objectForKey:@"data_1"];
    NSLog(@"getting colour : %@",parsed_data);
    [colours addObject:parsed_data];
    .....
    [self.mapMain reloadData];
}
```

where mapMain is my IBoutlet.
and for setting background:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier=@"SimpleTableCell";
    //this is the identifier of the custom cell
    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSLog(@"Colour at %d is %@ ",indexPath.row,[colours objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);


    if ([@"red" isEqualToString:[colours objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
        cell.mainImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[centersimages_red objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    } else{
    cell.mainImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[centersimages_green objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

where centerimages are tables with my .pngs names.

This is my log:

```
Colour at 0 is (null) 
Colour at 1 is (null)
....
didReceiveResponse
connectionDidFinishLoading
Succeeded! Received 287 bytes of data
getting colour for data : red
```

so it firsts assigns the image to cell and then does the request. And of course I always see the image in the else clause.

I want to do first the data fetching and then assign images. How to do it?
Because it is my first ios app please either complete the answer or give me sample code or give a link to a tutorial.

EDIT:
OK i fixed that typo error. And now I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I am trying to reload. if i uncomment the reload data this error does not show up. 
See my edited code. My table view is "connected" to IBOutlet mainMap.

EDIT2:
The error comes at this line:

```
 NSLog(@"Colour at %d is %@ ",indexPath.row,[colour objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

at the second time (I mean when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called because of the reload Data)

error is: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 1).
Maybe array is released or something like this? What should I check for that?

Comment: [tableView reloadData] after your request is complete.

Comment: where tableView is the name of my IBOutlet?

Comment: In case your tableView is connected as an IBOutlet to a property that is named tableView, then it could be `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: I have placed it inside my connectionDidFinishLoading but nothing changed. watch my edited code.

Comment: WHAT IS THIS: `colours== [NSMutableArray array];`??? It has to be like THIS: `colours = [NSMutableArray array];`. Note the **SINGLE EQUALS SIGN**

Comment: Your line is really colours== [NSMutableArray array]; ? This compares, of course you want to assign (single =)

Comment: can you please watch my edit?

Comment: can you please post the exception output of the bad access? Would be very helpful. Please set a breakpoint inside your cellForRow method and step through, to find out, where the bad access happens!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do every thing as you do it, but hide the tableView after its initialization:

```
tableView.alpha = 0;
```

Then in your `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method after filling your array, first reload the tableView with `[tableView reloadData];` (that is calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` again) and then show your tableView with `tableView.alpha = 1;`.

You can also fade the tableView in and out with a animation, but that's another question.

If you want to know, how to write such a JSON-Parsing-tableView-filling App visit this link:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/

By the way:

WHAT IS THIS: `colours== [NSMutableArray array];`??? It has to be like THIS:

```
colours = [NSMutableArray array];.
```

Note the **SINGLE EQUALS SIGN**

Comment: ok i changed that and i have another mistake. Can you please watch my edit?